# What is LINQ operator to perform division operation on Tables?

Tags: sql, linq, relational-division

To select elements belonging to a particular group in Table, if elements and their group type are contained in one table and all group types are listed in another table we perform division on tables.
I am trying LINQ query to perform the same operation. Please tell me how can I do perform it?

Comment: not clear what you are trying to do and what you have done already. Give an example of your code or explain a bit more.

Comment: @Pleun division opeartor in relational databases as explained at
 http://sajidzaman.com/2010/12/16/division-operator-in-relational-databases/

Comment: @MaruthiRevankar: Why must we read a blog post in order to understand your question? Please edit it to make it clearer. Thanks.

Comment: I have not explained much because I cannot put my tables here. And its a general question. Its a small part of a large question. hence I am not putting my entire question and 80% of answer that i have completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently from the definition of that blog post you'd want to intersect and except.

```
Table1.Except(Table1.Intersect(Table2));
```

or rather in your case I'd guess

```
Table1.Where(d => !Table2.Any(t => t.Type == d.Type));
```

not so hard.

I don't think performance can be made much better, actually. Maybe with a groupby.

```
Table1.GroupBy(t => t.Type).Where(g => !Table2.Any(t => t.Type == g.Key)).SelectMany(g => g);
```

this should be better for performance. Only searches the second table for every kind of type once, not for every row in Table1.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to determine exactly what you're asking. But, it sounds like you are looking to determine the elements that are common in two tables or streams. If so, I think you want Intersect.

[Take a look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx)

It works something like this:

```
int[] array1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] array2 = { 2, 3, 4 };
var intersect = array1.Intersect(array2);
```

Returns 2 and 3.

The opposite of this would be Except().

Comment: [That isn't what relational division is.](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Comment: Right but it sounds likes what he wants to accomplish.